# Generic function which accepts different class name as arguments

Tags: c#

I am working with C# where I need to create a single method which can accept parameter as a class name.

like: -

```
Class A
{
   public string name {get;set;}
}

Class B
{
   public int age {get;set;}
}

Class C
{
   public decimal salary {get;set;}
}
```

A function will call MethodABC based on some condition.

```
Function1(){
A obj = new A();
 MethodaBC(obj);
}

Function2(){
B obj = new B();
 MethodaBC(obj);
}

Function3(){
C obj = new C();
 MethodaBC(obj);
}
```

Method definition is: -
Static MethodABC(....)

Within MethodABC, I need to do some operation based on which class object has been passed in MethodABC.

Comment: Did you define class A, B and C? Or are they built-in classes like `String` and `List`?

Comment: Where is the code you have so far?

Comment: Updated the post, added more code based scenarios. I can't put original code because that is soo complex.

Comment: _"I need to do some operation based on which class object has been passed in MethodABC"_ -- you're not making sense. Typically, this would be handled by having method overloads, one for each type of interest. Why aren't you doing it that way? What _have_ you tried? What is this _"some operation"_ of which you speak? If you are passing the object (which any code can inspect to determine the type), why do you also want to pass the type name of the object?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, method is deserializing an XML to class object so i am looking for a generic method to this job done.

Comment: Deserializing XML is best handled by framework APIs that already do all the work. But even if you want to write it yourself, you haven't been clear (and still aren't) about what this method is going to do with the type name, and what in this scenario is actually generalizable to a generic method (do you really mean "generic" as in "C# generics"?), and yet you still need to handle each type individually.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I have edited the question and explained as good as I can. 
But anyway, thanks for your feedback. I have applied different approach form boxing and unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the [activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class to help you.

Example:

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);

MyClass instance = (MyClass)Activator.Create(type);

//method example
public void ClassGet(string MyClassName,string blabla)
{
    object instance = Activator.Create(MyClassName);
}

// Call it like:

Gold g = new Gold();
g.ClassGet("MyClass", "blabla");
```

You can pass the class as object as well:

```
  //method example
    public void ClassGet(MyClass MyClassName,string blabla)
    {
        object instance = Activator.Create(MyClassName);
    }

    // Call it like:

    Gold g = new Gold();
    g.ClassGet(MyClass, "blabla");
```